# Display driver error when running/starting Adobe Photoshop CC

Tags: windows-10, freeze, adobe-photoshop, amd-radeon, display-driver

I've had this error for months now and as a result, I rarely use Photoshop. When I open or run Photoshop, there would be a time when Photoshop freezes and then the whole PC freezes as well. Both will then unfreeze, then I receive this error from the taskbar:

> **Display driver has stopped responding and has recovered**
>
> Display driver AMD driver has stopped responding and has successfully recovered

After receiving the error above, I attempt to close Photoshop but the PC would freeze if I do so.

Is there a way to fix this?

**Information:**

- Windows 10 Home Single Language (November Update, 1511)
- 64-bit Operating System
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHz 1.80 GHz
- RAM: 4.00 GB (3.89 GB usable)

**Update:** I would also like to inform that an automatic update on the AMD drivers last August. [image]

However, the sticker near the keyboard of my laptop says **Radeon Graphics HD 8530M** and not Radeon R5 M240. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Did you update the display driver from the AMD website? http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

Comment: No, I haven't. Actually I updated the AMD driver before to fix a past problem (see http://superuser.com/questions/994218/frequent-bsod-thread-stuck-in-device-driver) and I believe my problem with Photoshop started after that. Any advice before I update again?

Comment: Take a system back up so you can use a restore point

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for the late reply. I updated the post since I discovered something in my update history

Answer (score 0):

Radeon Graphics HD 8530M and Radeon R5 M240 mean the same thing, no problem there, it's just new naming scheme.

Your problem has something to do with GPU staying in IDLE / low power / low fq mode when it suppose not to.

**I had a similar issue when trying to start high GPU demanding apps immediately after waking from sleep mode.**

The solution was to give the PC 2 minutes to heat-up and then I could use the apps for any amount of time without any errors. This may sound trivial, but it's something I discovered to be working. To stop this behavior it's probably possible with some good driver tweaking.

Comment: Hi Overmind, what do you mean by giving the PC 2 mins to heat-up?

Comment: Do not run any GPU-demanding app when waking from sleep/hiber for the first 2 minutes. That includes games, recent browsers, video editing software. I mean a text editor would be fine but starting even a video player or browser may cause the DDSR/R error. The issue appear to be related on how the drivers access the GPU resources. They are unable to fully access the GPU immediately after wake-up. I found this issue on many post W7 computers.

Comment: I don't really make the PC sleep or hibernate. How else can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DisplayLink external devices than most likely the problem is with Display Link driver. The only way I got this to work is by disabling the original GPU and re-enabling in device manager, this happens after windows update. After you reboot your PC or Laptop you will need to Disable/Enable GPU again. Photoshop is working fine when there is no DisplayLink device plugged in to PC.

Photoshop is blaming GPU Drivers, DisplayLink is blaming USB Drivers, I got no where with support from adapter manufacturer.